# Grafico Google Charts

Tags: javascript

Encontrei esse exemplo no site do line-chasrts

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Mas considere o caso em que ocorra o seguinte:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2003',  870,          ],
    ['2004',  1000,      400],
    ['2005',  1170,      460],
    ['2006',  660,       1120],
    ['2007',  1030,      540]
]);
```

Note que na primeira linha **Expanses** não teve qualquer **combinação** com o ano **2003**

Isso vai gerar um erro.

Como fazer nesse caso?

Comment: Não era mais fácil fazer somente `['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2003',  870, 0 ]` ?

Answer (score 0):

O certo é tratar esse erro. Você pode usar um bloco `try`para isso:

```
      try {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
              ['2004',  1000,      ],
              ['2005',  1170,      460],
              ['2006',  660,       1120],
              ['2007',  1030,      540]
            ]);

            var options = {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            curveType: 'function',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
      } catch (e){
          alert("Não foi possível gerar o gráfico. Motivo: " + e); 
          // tratamento do erro é feito aqui!
      }
```

Após os comentáros, creio que entendi o receio de usar o vetor para turmas diferentes em horário corrido.

Então, criei uma solução:

Vai haver 2 arrays com apenas as quantidades de alunos em cada período, nos seus respectivos horários:

```
    var manha = [20, 30, 25, 40, 38]; // array dos horários da manhã
    var tarde = [32, 21, 42, 37, 32]; // array dos horarios da tarde
```

Depois insere os valores no vetor do gráfico e mostra a interface gráfica:

**O código ficará assim:**

```
  function drawChart() {

            var manha = [20, 30, 25, 40, 38]; // array dos horários da manhã
            var tarde = [32, 21, 42, 37, 32]; // array dos horarios da tarde

            var arr = [
                ['Semana', 'Turma da Manhã', 'Turma da Tarde'],
                ['7:30',  0,   0],
                ['8:30',  0,   0],
                ['9:30',  0,   0],
                ['10:30',  0,   0],
                ['11:30',  0,   0],
                ['12:30',  0,   0],
                ['13:30',  0,   0],
                ['14:30',  0,   0],
                ['15:30',  0,   0],
                ['16:30',  0,   0]
            ];

            var x = 1; var y = 1; // posição inicial

            // insere no gráfico os valores da manhã
            for(var i = 0; i < manha.length; i++){
                arr[x][y] = manha[i]; x++;
            }
            y = 2;
            // insere no gráfico os valores da tarde
            for(var i = 0; i < tarde.length; i++){
                arr[x][y] = tarde[i]; x++;
            }

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);

            var options = {
                title: 'Presença de alunos por horário',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);

  }
```

Isso irá impedir que haja os problemas com cargas horárias diferentes e você poderá apresentar o gráfico com os horários corridos.

Comment: Andrei obrigado pela resposta mas não era bem isso que euj preiso. É o seguinte. Considere um array (data, presentes) que traz essa comparaçao uma determinada turma de escola por exemplo. Mas o colégio tem outras turmas em outros horários. Considere pore xemplo a turma a no horario de 7 às 12hs e a turma B de 13 às 18hs, se os horários não batem das 2 turmas, como fazer esse gráfico mostrandp, no mesmo gráfico, o numero de alunos ffrequentes das 2 turmas? Ficou mais claro? Acho que o modelo do line-chart que estou us\ando não é o correto!

Comment: @CarlosRocha é só você dar nomenclatura as turmas. Vou inserir um exemplo.

Comment: @CarlosRocha lembrando que a sua pergunta não foi sobre isso né! =) ... A pergunta foi: Isso *vai gerar um erro. Como fazer nesse caso?*

Comment: posta um exemplo que ao invés de dia da semana traga a hora de funcionamento sabendo que uma turma funciona de 7 às 12 e outra de 13 às 18

Comment: @CarlosRocha dá uma olhada depois na edição que eu fiz. Na solução que eu criei.

Comment: mas nesse caso, setando as turmas que NÃO tem naquele horáro, você está dizendo que vieram 0 alunos o que não é real pois a turma não estará lá naquele horário. Mas pode tranqulamente ocorer de haver 0 alunos na turma em seu horário  normal. Acho que vou ter que estudar um pouco mais disso até porque paa eu poder fazer uma pergunta um pouco mais coerente com a minha necessidade. Valeu irmão!